# How to enable/disable a button based on condition/text change in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am automating some account details, where I DO NOT want them to add double double . 
for this I need to restrict button click event to once so that they are not added twice or trice.
How can I restrict a button click event , otherwise if I change any amount I want button back to update.
any help on this please.

```
 commandbutton1.enable = true
 commandbutton1.enable = false
```

This is working , but I want button back when ever my account values are changing in cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Worksheet_Change Event to re-enable the button

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
commandbutton1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

If you only want the button to be enabled when a certain cell is changed, do it like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'Adjust this Cell Address
    commandbutton1.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

If you want to check for multiple Cells, you can do it like this:

```
Dim testRange As Range

Set testRange = Range("A1,B3:B10,D5")

If Not Intersect(Target, testRange) Is Nothing Then

    'Do something
    Debug.Print "Target Cell in testRange"
End If
```

To Check if the changed Cell is in a certain row:

```
If Target.Row = 2 Then
```

For Columns:

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then
```

Comment: If I want to give multiple cell address how can I do that?
As I am having many cells to check..
many rows and many cols to check for change event

Comment: @SwethaReddy added some examples to the answer.

Comment: Thanks..! Really Helpful